# D separation python implementation

Tags: python-3.x, naivebayes, hidden-markov-models, bayesian-networks

I am completely new to the field of Bayesian Networks. For my project, I need to check **All the possible d separation conditions** existing in a 7 node dag and for that I am looking for some good python code.
My knowledge in programming is limited ( a bit of numerical analysis and data structures; but I understand d separation, e separation and other concepts in a dag quite well).

It would be really very helpful if someone could point out where to look for such a specific code. Please note that I want a python codes that checks for **All the conditional independences following from d separation in a 7 node dag**.

I would be happier with an
algorithm checking whether each path is blocked or not etc rather than one built on semi graphoid axioms.

I don't know exactly where should I look or to whom should I ask, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you understand that your demand is a very large list. Even if we only consider d-separation between only 2 variables (conditionned by a set of nodes).

Anyway, you can do that quite easily with pyAgrum (https://agrum.org)

```py
import itertools
import pyAgrum as gum

# create a BN
bn=gum.fastBN("A->B<-C->D->E->F;B->E<-G");

# print the indepency model by testing d-separations

# how to iterate for each subset of an interable
def powerset(iterable):
    """
    powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)
    """
    xs = list(iterable)
    # note we return an iterator rather than a list
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(xs,n) for n in range(len(xs)+1))

# testing every d-separation
for i in bn.names():
    for j in bn.names()-{i}:
        for k in powerset(bn.names()-{i,j}):
            if bn.isIndependent(i,j,k):
                print(f"{i} indep {j} given {k}")
```

And the result (in a notebook) :

[image: using pyAgrum for list of d-separations]

Comment: Kindly update your answer in order to also include the first code snippet as *text*.

Comment: I added the 2 lines to create the Bayesian network. Since this snippet is not necessarily intended for notebook, I did not put the 2 lines that display it as a directed graph (in a notebook). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made a package that accurately implements the function you want. What a coincidence!

```
pip install cdpi
```

```
from cdpi import pattern
ptn = pattern()
ptn.add_edges([
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('C', 'B'),
    ('B', 'D'),
    ('E', 'D'),
    ('F', 'D'),
    ('D', 'G')
])
ptn.draw()
```

[out] Graph visualization is also supported! but 10 reputations limit...  I can't upload image...

```
ds = ptn.get_all_d_separation() # ds is 2-d dictionary
ds['F']['A'] #example
```

[out]

```
{(),
 ('B',),
 ('B', 'C'),
 ('B', 'D'),
 ('B', 'D', 'C'),
 ('B', 'E'),
 ('B', 'E', 'C'),
 ('B', 'E', 'D'),
 ('B', 'E', 'D', 'C'),
 ('B', 'E', 'D', 'G'),
 ('B', 'E', 'G'),
 ('B', 'E', 'G', 'C'),
 ('B', 'G'),
 ('B', 'G', 'C'),
 ('C',),
 ('E',),
 ('E', 'C'),
 ('G', 'B', 'D'),
 ('G', 'B', 'D', 'C'),
 ('G', 'E', 'C', 'B', 'D')}
```

If you want to see entire code or how it works, see [d-separation part](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GZ6lX4RzSzSJriIe5_t-tRYZd4YULxoF?usp=share_link) of [here](https://github.com/papamoon0113/Causal-Discovery-Python-Implement)